Exception thrown after "Refresh EventLog Source"
I've enabled NLog internal logging to figure out an issue where our logs suddenly stop sometimes.
Might be unrelated to the issue I'm trying to figure out but I've gotten this Exception for one of the targets (FileTarget logging with ConcurrentWrites = true, wrapped by AsyncTargetWrapper).
This is a file where a couple of running applications should be able to write to. Before this error this file is already created and written to
I'm currently running NLog version 5.2.8 on all applications
FileTarget Config:
 var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
_config.AddTarget("file", new AsyncTargetWrapper(fileTarget));
fileTarget.FileName = "${gdc:logDirectory:whenEmpty=${gdc:defaultLogPath}}/${gdc:iisApplicationName:whenEmpty=${processname}}/${logger}.txt";
fileTarget.Layout = @"${longdate}: thread:${threadid} - ${level} ${message}";
fileTarget.ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day;
fileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date;
fileTarget.ArchiveFileName = "${gdc:logDirectory:whenEmpty=${gdc:defaultLogPath}}/${processname}/Archive/${logger}.{#}.txt";
fileTarget.ArchiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
fileTarget.MaxArchiveFiles = 10;

The path we're writing to resolves to: C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\Application\Logs\ServiceX(Archive)\File.txt
The error is:
2024-07-22 12:35:33.2512 Debug EventLogTarget([unnamed]): Refresh EventLog Source Company.WCF.Client.Console - Client and Log Application
2024-07-22 12:35:33.2512 Debug FileTarget([unnamed]): Preparing for new file: 'C:\ProgramData\Company\Logs\AllExceptions.txt'
2024-07-22 12:35:33.2512 Debug FileTarget([unnamed]): Creating file appender: 'C:\ProgramData\Company\Logs\AllExceptions.txt'
2024-07-22 12:35:33.2512 Warn FileTarget([unnamed]): Failed to create file appender: C:\ProgramData\Company\Logs\AllExceptions.txt Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Company\Logs\AllExceptions.txt' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileSystemRights rights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.WindowsMultiProcessFileAppender.CreateAppendOnlyFile(String fileName)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.WindowsMultiProcessFileAppender..ctor(String fileName, ICreateFileParameters parameters)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.WindowsMultiProcessFileAppender.Factory.NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.IFileAppenderFactory.Open(String fileName, ICreateFileParameters parameters)
   at NLog.Internal.FileAppenders.FileAppenderCache.CreateAppender(String fileName, Int32 freeSpot)

Could I get an explanation on why this could be triggered? This seems to have happened while the applications were running on my development machine, without any intervention at that timestamp

System.UnauthorizedAccessException - You probably don't have access to that path under the credentials NLog is running under.  If you change the path to something that is open like C:\Temp or something with less permissions, does it work?

You have decided not to include your NLog.config-file, but I'm guessing that you have configured both file-target and eventlog-target as output for error/exception-events.
Thus both file-target and eventlog-target reacts to the same error/exception-event, and have different reactions. The eventlog-target "refreshes" its EventLog-source, and the file-target detects that it doesn't have write-permissions.
Maybe the NLog.config-file have 2 file-targets that points to the same file-path (Thus the file-path is already open by other file-target). Or maybe you have 2 application-instances running concurrently and writing to the same file (Ex. IIS-instance of the same web-application).
If you want applications instances to share the same file-path, instead of having their own unique file-path, then consider enabling keepFileOpen=false or concurrentWrites=true. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target
Could also be that the application is running with an user-account that does not have permission to the file-path. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

I will add the config of the FileTarget to the original question. As far as I can tell we should have only one application per log folder (with multiple files)  . The only thing we can think of, and still need to check, is if it could possibly be triggered by async code trying to write to the same file more or less at the same time. But that does not explain why I have UnauthorizedAccessExceptions on deleting the oldest Archive files sometimes as well (these archived files are written to an added child folder in the main log folder of the application).
